# Is it possible to schedule table update/refresh in Oracle Application Express?

Tags: sql-server, oracle

I have SQL Server data dumped into a text or csv file available via HTTP. Is is possible to schedule Apex to create a table on that data and keep it updated? How?

Answer (score 1):

You can do the following steps in a procedure:
1) User UTL_HTTP to read the csv file;
2) Save the file on a oracle directory;
3) Create an external table that will map this CSV file;
4) Schedule this procedure accordingly, using dbms_job_scheduler

This assumes your user has permissions to execute UTL_HTTP, UTL_FILE and DBMS_JOB_SCHEDULER, besides read/write permission in the given oracle directory.